# how to keep a header parameter in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, authentication, header, token, jwt

I have made a JWT authentication for my rest api. now i can login in my service and set a token in header for my next angular requests. But when a reload my page browser lost my token. May sounds like ridiculous, but i want to know the elegant way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the JWT token in localStorage or sessionStorage and append it to the header when making requests.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: ok, so i  put this header for every request i need . got it.   is the best way  to made a  rest authentication? is safety?

Comment: I would suggest you read the intro for jwt https://jwt.io/introduction/ in case you haven't already and the different types of tokens https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/ then you can make a better decision on where to store the token. There's also lots of articles on the Internet on how to securely store the token.